# Why is Canvas not working inside of an If statement?

Tags: javascript, canvas, discord.js, replit

I'm trying to make my code only show a piece of text when the database is gives a certain value.

```js
const canvas = Canvas.createCanvas(250, 250);
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.fillStyle = message.content;
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.height, canvas.width)

db.get("label"+message.author.id).then(value => {
   console.log(value)
   if(value == 'on') {
     console.log('true')
       ctx.font = '40px Poppins';
       ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff';
     ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000'
     ctx.lineWidth = 1; 
       ctx.fillText(message.content, canvas.width/10,       canvas.height / 2 + 20);
          ctx.strokeText(message.content, canvas.width/10, canvas.height / 2 + 20);
   }
})
```

This is what I have so far. Unfortunately, no matter the value in the database, it won't add the text. I've tested it without this stuff, and it adds the text. Can someone tell me how to fix this?

Edit: Here's my complete and total code for this problem:

```js
  if(message.content.startsWith('#') && message.content.length == 7) {
      const canvas = Canvas.createCanvas(250, 250);
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

      ctx.fillStyle = message.content;
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.height, canvas.width)

      db.get("label"+message.author.id).then(value => {
        console.log(value)
        if(value == 'on') {
          console.log('true')
            ctx.font = '40px Poppins';
            ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff';
          ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000'
          ctx.lineWidth = 1; 
            ctx.fillText(message.content, canvas.width/10, canvas.height / 2 + 20);
          ctx.strokeText(message.content, canvas.width/10, canvas.height / 2 + 20);
        }
      })
      

      
        
  const attachment = new Discord.MessageAttachment(canvas.toBuffer(), 'color.png');
  message.channel.send(attachment)
 }
```

Comment: Is canvas supported in discord ? (I imagine you are writing some kind of bot). I haven't written anything for discord so I don't really know

Comment: Also what do you get when you do console.log(value);

Answer (score 0):

You aren't **sending** the Canvas image, you're just building it. When you've finished building the image, you should use [**Canvas#toBuffer**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas#canvastobuffer) to make it compatible with [**discordjs#MessageAttachment**](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageAttachment).

```
  const { MessageAttachment } = require('discord.js')
  const canvas = Canvas.createCanvas(250, 250);
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  ctx.fillStyle = message.content
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.height, canvas.width)

  db.get('label' + message.author.id).then(value => {
    console.log(value)
    if (value == 'on') {
      console.log('true')
      ctx.font = '40px Poppins'
      ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff'
      ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000'
      ctx.lineWidth = 1
      ctx.fillText(message.content, canvas.width / 10, canvas.height / 2 + 20)
      ctx.strokeText(message.content, canvas.width / 10, canvas.height / 2 + 20)
      message.reply({
        files: [new MessageAttachment(canvas.toBuffer(), 'fileName.png')]
      })
    }
  })
```

Comment: Yes, I left that part out of the code, but I have that.